# Moz API call times out

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express

I'm using node to make Moz API request. This is my code:

```
function MozCall(callback) {
  var mozCall = '';

  // Set your expires times for several minutes into the future.
  // An expires time excessively far in the future will not be honored by the Mozscape API.
  // Divide the result of Date.now() by 1000 to make sure your result is in seconds.
  var expires = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 300;
  var accessId = 'key';
  var secretKey = 'key';

  // `bitFlagExampleValues` is a list of bitFlag values as strings that we'll
  // loop over and sum together using helper function: `sumColumnValues`
  var bitFlagExampleValues = [
    '144115188075855872',
    '68719476736',
    '34359738368',
  ];
  var sumColumnValues = function(bitFlagValues) {
    return bitFlagValues.reduce(function(accu, bitFlag) {
      var accuValBig = new bigJs(accu);
      var bitFlagBig = new bigJs(bitFlag);
      var bigSum = accuValBig.plus(bitFlagBig);

      return bigSum.toString();
    }, 0);
  };

  // 'cols' is the sum of the bit flags representing each field you want returned.
  // Learn more here: https://moz.com/help/guides/moz-api/mozscape/api-reference/url-metrics
  // returns "144115291155070976"
  var cols = sumColumnValues(bitFlagExampleValues);

  // Put each parameter on a new line.
  var stringToSign = accessId + '\n' + expires;

  //create the hmac hash and Base64-encode it.
  var signature = crypto
    .createHmac('sha1', secretKey)
    .update(stringToSign)
    .digest('base64');
  //URL-encode the result of the above.
  signature = encodeURIComponent(signature);

  var postData = JSON.stringify([
    website,
    'www.apple.com',
    'www.pizza.com',
  ]);

  var options = {
    hostname: 'lsapi.seomoz.com',
    path:
      '/linkscape/url-metrics/?Cols=' +
      cols +
      '&AccessID=' +
      accessId +
      '&Expires=' +
      expires +
      '&Signature=' +
      signature,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Content-Length': postData.length,
    },
  };

  var responseData = '';

  var req = http.request(options, function(response) {
    response.setEncoding('utf8');
    response.on('data', function(chunk) {
      responseData += chunk;
    });
    response.on('end', function() {
      console.log(responseData);
    });
  });
  req.end()
}
// if (req.user.isPremium == false) {
let freeReportCalls = [MozCall];
// Free user - Single report
// let website = req.body.website0;
async.parallel(freeReportCalls, function(err, results) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log(results);
    res.render('reports/report', {
      title: 'Report',
      // bw: JSON.parse(results[0]),
      // ps: JSON.parse(results[0]),
      // bw: results[1],
      // al: results[2],
      // moz: results[2],
      user: req.user,
    });
  }
});
```

I took this code from their github examples, which can be found here: https://github.com/seomoz/SEOmozAPISamples/blob/master/javascript/node/batching-urls-sample.js

But every time I make the call I get this error.

```
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:331:15)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:423:23)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1055:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

Since event.js is a part of a package I'm pretty much sure I'm doing something wrong, but I have no idea what. I tried breaking the API key but it looks like it just doesn't want to connect to Moz servers. Any idea what's wrong here?

Edit: I found this discussion but I'm not sure if it's related to the issue https://github.com/Automattic/knox/issues/116

Edit2: I added a `req.end()` which solved the timeout issue. Now I'm getting a `503, service temporarily unavailable`. Any idea which service they're talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok adding `req.end()` at the end solved the timeout issue. I'll open another post for my new problem.